# Dynamoose + DynamoDB query logic

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with a primary key (_id) being a simple int. I want to get the highest value for the primary key.

How do I return the item in the table with the highest _id?

I can use either the Amazon javascript API or the Dynamoose library.

Answer (score 0):

Partition keys are not stored in order. You would need to scan the entire table, stream over the items, map to the _id attribute and then return the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create Global Secondary Index where _id must to be a sort key and based on it you can make a request like this:

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'Devices',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'status = :status',
    ScanIndexForward: false,    // true = ascending, false = descending
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':s': status
    }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {});
```